# Navigate through an animation with a single key

Tags: animation, game-engine

I'm using the game engine of blender and I would like to be able to use the same key to incrementally trigger different animation part. For example, pressing the right arrow one time should play frame 1 to 60 for a given object animation and if pressed a second time it should play frame 61 to 120... (And so on) Any Idea how I could achieve that ?

Thanks

Philip

Here is the code I made to solve my problem. I'm using two keyboard sensors (could have used only one set to all keys but I'm n00b in Python and Blender so...) and a game property "counter".

```
import bge, GameLogic
cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
scene = GameLogic.getCurrentScene()
#slideNumberDisplay=scene.objects['Text']
obj = cont.owner
nextAction = cont.sensors['Next']
previousAction = cont.sensors['Previous']

def navigate( direction ):
    if direction == 'next':
        startFrame = (obj['counter'] * 40) + 1
        obj['counter'] = obj['counter'] + 1
        endFrame = obj['counter'] * 40
    elif direction == 'previous':
        endFrame = ((obj['counter'] - 1) * 40) + 1
        startFrame = obj['counter'] * 40
        obj['counter'] = obj['counter'] - 1
    #slideNumberDisplay['Text'] = obj['counter']
    obj.playAction("PresentationAction", startFrame, endFrame, 0, 1, 1.0, bge.logic.KX_ACTION_MODE_PLAY, 0.0, 0, 1.0)
    return;

if nextAction.positive:
    print(nextAction.key)
    navigate('next')

elif previousAction.positive:
    print(previousAction.key)
    navigate('previous')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done relatively easily with a logic setup similar to this:

[image: !Image of Logic would normally be here. The message to Googlebot lower is a gif of the working result.]

Here the only game property we will need is an Integer property. It is named **Animation,** but you could name it anything you want.

The *Actuator* sensors are triggered when a certain action is being executed, by inverting the output, it will only activate when the action has finished extincting. This means that, after you press <kbd>➔</kbd> and **Animation** is equal to 1, frames 0-60 of your animation will play. When the animation has played up to frame 60, the first *actuator* sensor will trigger, increasing **Animation** by one, so the next time you press <kbd>➔</kbd>, the next animation will play. The same thing will happen for frames 61-120, and frames 121-180, Except that, on frame 180, **Animation** is assigned increased from 3 to 4, and the set to 1 again so the animation can loop again. You could have as many *Play* actuators as you want before you loop the animation, but it was easiest to do three for this example.

(we need to test it)

[image: Hi Googlebot, this message is just for you! it's me again!]

### It Works - YaY!!

of course, if you don't feel like re making that yourself, you can always take apart/play with/modify the blend file. :-)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you answer ! I couldn't figure out how to achieve this with the GUI. Finally, I wrote some Python code ;-)